# Only one messagebar created but says there's "1 more"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

Using QGIS 3.14.1. If I type

```
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(iface.messageBar().createMessage( u'Hello World' ), Qgis.Info)
```

into the python console, it says there's "1 more message". But no other messages are created.

Is this a bug?

[image: messagebar inserted]

Comment: I think it's simpler and cleaner to write `iface.messageBar().pushInfo("", "Hello World")`. Here, it's like you do a MessageBar-ception.

Comment: Thanks @J.Monticolo but I need the message to be there at all times. Your code has a default timing of 3 seconds or so.

Comment: so, use this `iface.messageBar().pushMessage("", "Hello World", Qgis.Info, -1)`. Here `-1` fix an unlimited duration.

Comment: @J.Monticolo nice! that is a lot neater, thank you!